# Regex returning True and False in the file

Tags: python, csv

Basically, I'm trying to write invalid registrations to a file; only when I'm trying to write it, it comes up as `true` and `false` in the files, (maybe because it's a boolean value?). I've tried to convert it to string, but that didn't do any good, so I was wondering if anyone could give me a few tips TIA?

My code:

```
Reg = element[0].strip("\n")
rule = "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}"

file3 = open("InvalidReg.csv","w")
file4 = open("ValidReg.csv","w")

invalid  = re.search !=(rule,Reg)
file3.write(str(invalid))

valid = re.search == (rule,Reg)
file4.write(str(valid))
```

Comment: Please do come up with better titles. *Any* post with the `[python]` tag is about Python problems. What is your post about, why should someone want to look at it from the list of questions?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for regular expressions in Python. What do you think you are doing with `invalid  = re.search !=(rule,Reg)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not compleately sure what your question demands, but as far as i comphreanded it, `True` and `False` are being printed to your file, which is not the desired output?

Well that's because `re.search` returns a `Match Object`, For example:

```
>>> search_string = 'piiig'
>>> output = re.search('iii', search_string)
>>> output
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fac84d359f0>

>>> if output:
...  print "Something"
...
Something

>>> print output
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fac84d359f0>
```

So when you're doing:

```
invalid  = re.search !=(rule,Reg)
file3.write(str(invalid))
```

It looks for the pattern and then prints `True` if the pattern matches and `False` if pattern doesnot matches.

You'll have to call the `.group()` function in `re.search` module to get the result:

```
>>> output.group() 
'iii'
```

So when modified accordingly, your code will become:

```
file3.write(str(invalid.group()))
```

I'd suggest padding it up with a `try/catch` clause or it'll throw an error when there is no element in the group object.